# Внутренний <router-outlet name="mypage"></router-outlet>. Angular 7

Tags: angular, spa, angular7

На данный момент все работает. Но проблема в том что ссылка отображается коряво с название роутер отлета http://prntscr.com/nvm0dd

Я хочу что б было как у людей  profile/mymessage

Вот код файла роут

```
  const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: LoginComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
 },
 {
path: 'profile',
component: ProfileComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'mymessage',
    component: MymessageComponent,
    outlet: 'mypage'
  },
 ]
 },
 ];
```

есть первый rout outlet и в уже дочерний с именем. Вот код

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {mypage: ['mymessage'] } }]">
<mat-sidenav-content>
<router-outlet name="mypage"></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

Цель одна. Добиться что б ссылка была нормальной profile/mymessage

Comment: это не "корявое отображение", как вы назвали, а нормальное отображение для именованного аутлета

Comment: есть возможность его убрать?

Comment: убрать также как и добавили. С какой целью вы используете именованный аутлет?

Comment: Ну есть главный аутлет. Он ведет на профайл где есть боковая панель. В боковой панедели сайд-бар + его контент збоку. Вот в контент я вставил еще один аутлет. И там уже внутри профайла по страницами profile/mymessage, profile/mycontacts перемещается юзер

Comment: вы отвечаете глобально как вы организовали роутинг, вы не ответили на главный вопрос > С какой целью вы используете именованный аутлет?

Comment: Один глобальный, другой для юзера на странице профайл с именем "mypage". Второй аутлет нужен для перемещения по профайлу.

Comment: это не ответ. Чем не подходит обычный аутлет, зачем именованный?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94325/discussion-between-fx-sektor-and-overthesanity).